# Regular Expression to remove space other than once in quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Need a regular expression using which can remove space with in characters other than one in quotes

For example. let say we have string

Input: Want to " " change the world1.

Then after using regular expression remove the output should be

Output: Wantto" "changetheworld1.

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but this ought to do:

```
String.Join("\" \"", myStr.Split("\" \"").Select(x=>x.Replace(" ","")).ToArray())
```

It is not a regular expression, but I believe this is much easier. Writing a regular expression to do what you want will involve lookahead and lookbehind and will honestly just be ugly.

Comment: +1: Regexs are very powerful and have their place, but they're not the ideal solution for every piece of text processing.

Comment: Right but actually the requirement in of Regex

Comment: Isn't it sarcastic. I asked a question with my requirement and haven't asked for alternates. Please focus on question.

Comment: @Asoo You have not answered why this is "the requirement" which leads me to believe this is indeed homework. If you asked how to use a circular saw to carve a turkey, I believe everyone would suggest "use a knife". This is no different. I also hope you are not the downvoter because, frankly, you are quite being rude. We are not your lackeys; SO is a community of programmers working to help each other! If you want a lackey, try rent-a-coder or something.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex

output : Wantto" " changetheworld1

```
Regex.Replace("Want to " " change the world1",@"([a-zA-z]+)[\s]","$1")
```

Comment: To match anything in double quotes you need more than that character class. Eg. `".+?"`. But the Q doesn't say what to do about non-spaces in quotes. But the idea of using a regex replace to preserve does make the regex easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting puzzle.

Please try this one:

```cs
Regex.Replace("A test \" \" string", @"(?<!["" ])[ ]+|(?>[ ]+)(?!"")", "")
```

The output will be 'Atest" "string'.

Comment: I suppose it isn't ugly and looks more friendly then Join/Split/Select :)